# How to deserialize xml using Linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can i deserialize this xml using Linq?
I want to create `List<Step>`

```
<MySteps>
  <Step>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Step 1</Name>
    <Description>Step 1 Description</Description>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Name>Step 2</Name>
    <Description>Step 2 Description</Description>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <Name>Step 3</Name>
    <Description>Step 3 Description</Description>
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <Name>Step 4</Name>
    <Description>Step 4 Description</Description>
  </Step>
</MySteps>
```

Comment: A List of what? Have you defined your own List class? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Any reason for using not just using `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`?

Comment: i am trying to use the Linq to xml with no success

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
string xml = @"<MySteps>
                <Step>
                    <ID>1</ID>
                    <Name>Step 1</Name>
                    <Description>Step 1 Description</Description>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <ID>2</ID>
                    <Name>Step 2</Name>
                    <Description>Step 2 Description</Description>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <ID>3</ID>
                    <Name>Step 3</Name>
                    <Description>Step 3 Description</Description>
                </Step>
                <Step>
                    <ID>4</ID>
                    <Name>Step 4</Name>
                    <Description>Step 4 Description</Description>
                </Step>
                </MySteps>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var mySteps = (from s in doc.Descendants("Step")
               select new 
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(s.Element("ID").Value),
                    Name = s.Element("Name").Value,
                    Description = s.Element("Description").Value
                }).ToList();
```

Heres how you would do it using LINQ. Obviously you should be doing your own error checking.

Comment: I am doing something similar but this code only returns the first element...not a list?

Answer (score 4):

[LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) is your answer.

```
List<Step> steps = (from step in xml.Elements("Step")
                    select new Step()
                    {
                        Id = (int)step.Element("Id"),
                        Name = (string)step.Element("Name"),
                        Description = (string)step.Element("Description")
                    }).ToList();
```

And a bit about doing the conversions from XML from [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ImprovingLINQCodeSmellWithExplicitAndImplicitConversionOperators.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Showing the above answers in LINQ method syntax

Descendants:

```
var steps = xml.Descendants("Step").Select(step => new
{
    Id = (int)step.Element("ID"),
    Name = step.Element("Name").Value,
    Description = step.Element("Description").Value
});
```

Elements:

```
var steps2 = xml.Element("MySteps").Elements("Step").Select(step => new
{
    Id = (int)step.Element("ID"),
    Name = step.Element("Name").Value,
    Description = step.Element("Description").Value
});
```